# Pass fetch data to components using useState React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, fetch-api, use-state

I am new to React Native. Actually this is my first app.

I have been trying to pass data from Fetch to components, but no luck there. I have researched Google up and down, left and right, tried million things, but still no go.

This is my App.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

import Header from './parts/header';
// import BigNews from './parts/big-news';
import Index from './screens/index.js';

const authorization = { authorization: '1234aa' };

export default function App() {
  const [fetchApiData, setApiData] = useState();

  useEffect(() =>
  fetch('https://example.com/get-app-home.php', {
    method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(authorization),
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    this.setState({ setApiData: res })
  })
  .catch(() => this.setState({ hasErrors: true }))
  );
  return (
    <View style={styles.viewport}>
      <Header />
      <ScrollView style={styles.contentHolder}>
        <Index content={fetchApiData}/>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
);


}
```

And this is my index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

import BigNews from '../parts/big-news';
import SmallNews from '../parts/small-news';
import Colors from '../constants/colors'

const Index = props => {

    return (
      <View>
        <BigNews
        image={props.content.first.image}
        pretitle={props.content.first.pretitle}
        title={props.content.first.title}
        introduction={props.content.first.introduction}
        style={{color: props.content.first.mark}}/>

        <SmallNews
        image={props.content.second.image}
        pretitle={props.content.second.pretitle}
        title={props.content.second.title}
        style={{color: props.content.first.mark}}/>

        <SmallNews
        image={props.content.second.image}
        pretitle={props.content.second.pretitle}
        title={props.content.second.title}
        style={{color: props.content.first.mark}}/>

        <SmallNews
        image={props.content.second.image}
        pretitle={props.content.second.pretitle}
        title={props.content.second.title}
        style={{color: props.content.first.mark}}/>
      </View>
    );
}
export default Index;
```

I am constantly getting TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.content.first')

I tried million ways, but most of the times this is the error that I see. If I do console.log of state I get either undefined or empty.

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting your data `this.setState` is for class components. Replace `this.setState` with `setApiData()`.

`useState` returns the initial state and a fucntion to update that value.

```
const [ hasError, setHasErrors] = useState(false);

.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => {
  setApiData(res)
})
.catch(() => setHasErrors(true))
);
```

As George pointed out, the initial state is set to empty, doing `props.content.first.image` will result in an error. Either set the initial value to an object like

```
const [ fetchApiData, setApiData ] = useState({
   first: {},
   second: {}
});
```

or validate the values in your component.

```
const Index = props => {

  return (
   <View>
    <BigNews
    image={props && props.content && props.content.first && props.content.first.image}
    pretitle={props && props.content && props.content.pretitle && props.content.first.pretitle}
    title={props && props.content && props.content.title && props.content.first.title}
    introduction={props && props.content && props.content.introduction && props.content.first.introduction}
    style={{color: props && props.content && props.content.first && props.content.first.mark}}/>

    ...
  </View>
  );
}
export default Index;
```

Comment: @Korovjov Note that although this isn't the cause of the error you are getting, it still holds true.

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.content.first')

Comment: George' s answer about state, and as you pointed out, is correct. No problem there. But now React throws an error TypeError destroy is not a function. And I can not find that error on Google at all.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Index` component, the `content` prop is initially undefined as you don't pass any value (often referred to as "initial state") to the `useState` function in your `App` component.

Instead, try:

```
const [ fetchApiData, setApiData ] = useState({
    first: {},
    second: {}
});
```

Note that I've populated the initial state with the `first` and `second` items, because trying to access the elements further down the tree (`image`, `pretitle`, etc,) will still throw an error.

Comment: Ok, you solved one problem. Now I got the error: TypeError: destroy is not a function (In destroy(), destroy is an instance of Promise)

Comment: @Korovjov Sounds like cause for another question. Be specific.

Comment: That' s specific as it gets. That is error. Nothing more. https://ibb.co/YN5F4x3

Comment: Ok, I got it, the problem was with async await in Fetch API. I had to create async function. Is there any way I could achieve this (that you proposed first {}, second {}) without manually typing first, second, etc.... I mean is there any other way?